# Google Sheets - How to set a daily shift reminder on sheets (kind of)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I've been trying to do this for a while but can't find a solution. At work there is a special task that needs to be done daily by different people, on rotating shifts. I am trying to create a simple file in sheets in which you can go and clearly see who should be doing that tasks that day.

The data comes from a schedule that is located within the same file. Every day different people are supposed to do these tasks

So what I am trying to do is basically a formula (s) that will recognize what day is today and present it so everyone knows who is supposed to do those tasks today. This should update itself everyday, taking the data from the database. So if today is Friday 20/08/2022 it will show whatever is on the database for that date. If today is Saturday 21/08/2022 it will update and reflect what the schedule/database has.

Sounds pretty easy but I dont know where to start.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(C:G; A:A=TODAY())
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much. Do you know how can I set up a function or script that will send a daily message to a Google Chat group with the information about who works that day?

Comment: @coffee709 you will need a script for that but unfortunately, I am not capable of advising you on this topic

Comment: Awesome, I will try to find out how. Last question if you have time, what if I want this schedule to only show on sheet A but I have the data on sheet B. How do I reference the data from the other sheet? They have names, sheet A is called TODAY and sheet B is called SCHEDULE. Any ideas?

Comment: @coffee709 try: `=FILTER(SCHEDULE!C:G; SCHEDULE!A:A=TODAY())`